# Formatted varchar to decimal

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

For complicated reasons, I need to do this

```
FORMAT(CAST(ROUND(column) AS INT), '#,0.0000')
```

That gives me 1,000,000.0000

But how to get it back from varchar to decimal(12,4) later?

Thanks!

Comment: don't cast it back! you only have 4 digits in the varchar version and may fall foul of representation/rounding issues. Use the original decimal value

Comment: @DStanley it raises an error, but following works
SELECT CAST(REPLACE('1,000,000.0000', ',','') AS DECIMAL(12,4))
Thanks for an idea, but just wasn't sure is it best way, and safe way.

Comment: Formatting an _integer_ for display with an accuracy down to a ten-thousandth is interesting enough. Removing the culture-specific thousands separators in order to convert it to a numeric data type with such accuracy is bewildering. Tip: Formatting values for display is, as a rule, best handled in the application, not the database.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the commas and convert.  So:

```
DECLARE @x varchar(255);

SELECT @x = FORMAT(CAST(ROUND(column) AS INT), '#,0.0000');

SELECT CAST(REPLACE(@x, ',', ..) as DECIMAL(12, 4));
```